# How to disable function, e. g. SUM in only one Tab

Tags: excel, function, vba

I would like to know if there is posibbility to disable function like SUM or custom function (created in VBA), so that user will not be able to use it in one, defined tab but will be ale to use it on all other tabs?

Kind regards

Comment: You can do a check in a Worksheet_Change event to test if the function is one of the banned function.

Comment: You might have to disable automatic calculations for that worksheet in the `Worksheet_Change` event that @ScottCraner mentioned in order to prevent those banned functions from executing. Alert the user to remove the functions, then enable automatic calculations if there are no banned functions.

Comment: Thanks for help :)